# GNU sort's handling of URLs with UTF-8 - where is this documented?

Tags: sort, locale

This hurts my mind:

```
echo -e "http://z.com\nhttps://a.com" | sort

vs.

echo -e "http://z.com\nhttps://a.com" | LC_ALL=C sort
```

It seems sort ignores http vs https when sorting under UTF-8. But what is really driving me batty is that I can't find a single shred of documentation about this behavior. Can someone please point me to it?

Comment: What is your `locale`?

Comment: It's en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the `C` locale, `sort` sorts in the order given by the raw bytes; in the `en_US` locale, `sort` sorts in the culturally-appropriate lexicographical order:

- In the `C` locale:

  `http://z` sorts before `https://a` because `':'` (58) is less than `'s'` (115).
- In the `en_US` locale:

  `https://a` sorts before `http://z` because the American English lexicographical order ignores separators, so that the strings are collated as if they were `httpsa` and `httpz`, and obviously `s` comes before `z`.

[`man 1 sort`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/sort.1.html) says:

```
     ***  WARNING  ***  The locale specified by the environment affects sort
     order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native
     byte values.
```

To change just the sort order you can set the `LC_COLLATE` environment variable:

```
$ echo -e 'ab:d\nabc:d' | LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8 sort
abc:d
ab:d

$ echo -e 'ab:d\nabc:d' | LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8 sort
ab:d
abc:d
```

Note: the environment variable `LC_ALL` takes precedence over the detailed `LC_` variables.

Comment: Where did you find that en_US ignores the colon and slash?

Comment: @robbie.huffman: It ignores not only colon and slash but most separators, including for example spaces. Actually, it does not ignore them, but uses them only as a last resort do distinguish strings. In Debian etc. look in the locale definition file `/usr/share/i18n/locales/en_US`; this file copies the collation sequence from `iso14651_t1` ([`ISO 14651`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_14651) is an international standard describing string comparison rules); one more level of indirection and you get the actual collation rules, where space, colon and slash are defined as ignorable separators.